# AJAX - setting parent object's member variables from callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, scope

I'm developing a Javascript libraray which I want to use as follows.

```
var obj = new Lib().actionOne();
```

This call should populate "transcript" and "session" member variables in obj.
Then I want to call:

```
obj.actionTwo();
```

which will use populated "transcript" and "session" objects in the previous call.

Find below my library.

```
var xmlhttp = null;

function Lib() {        
   this.transcript = null;
   this.session = null;

   return this;
} 



Lib.prototype = {

    _initRequest : function() {
        // create xmlhttp request here
    },

    _consumeService : function(callback) {
        this._initRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "THE URL", true);
        var self = this;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(self) {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 ){  
                callback.call(self);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send(); 
    },


    actionOne: function() {
        var connUrl = "SOME URL";   
        this._consumeService(this._actionOneCallback);      

        return this;
    },  

    _actionOneCallback : function() {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        this.session = jsonObj.session
        this.transcript = jsonObj.transcript;

        this.isActionOneDone = true;
        xmlhttp = null;                 
    },

    actionTwo : function() {
        // use this.session and this.transcript
    }
};
```

The issue is that actionOneCallback() function doest not populate 'obj' members though I pass 'self' reference to it. Therefore when I call 'obj.actionTwo();', obj's member variables are undefined. What is the workaround for this?

Comment: Your daignosis is wrong, the referenced object IS getting updated, it just isn't updated by the time you try to access them. To prove this, wrap `obj.actionTwo();` in a setTimeout with a 10 second delay. After 10 seconds, said data will be available (assuming the ajax request doesn't take longer than 10 seconds). this is because ajax is asynchronous. The normal way of handling this is either to have action one return a deferred object, or have action one accept a callack, within which you call action 2.

Comment: @kevin-b tried this with two button clicks where button1 calls actionOne() and update a page with response. Then I click button2 which will call actionTwo() of the same object. But it didn't work as expected. When I inspected with firebug, I could confirm that callback function does not update 'obj' members. By the way, can you explain the technique of returning a deferred object?

Comment: First we need to make sure that you're actually having a race condition before you make sweeping changes to your code. Did you try the setTimeout i mentioned before?

Comment: @kevin-b Yes I did and no race condition occured. Becase I call actionTwo() only after writing the rsponse of first call. Appreciate your help here to resolve the issue.